# How to send The Authenticated user's ID inside JWT in spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, jwt, angular5

I'm working on a simple application With Spring boot as back end , and Angular5 as front End , I'm using spring security with JWT to authenticate users etc .

I need now to get the authenticated user's ID in angular5 , so i need to store it in JWT token before sending it to front end .

This is the method of succesfull authentication in spring boot :

```
 @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

        User springUser = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();
        String jwt = Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(springUser.getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                .claim("roles",springUser.getAuthorities())
                .compact();

     AppUser app = userRepo.findByUsername(springUser.getUsername());
     Long id = app.getId();

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonJwt = objectMapper.readTree(jwt);
    ((ObjectNode)jsonJwt).put("userId", id);

     System.out.println("this ! "+jsonJwt);


response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonJwt));

                   }
```

any idea on how to do this ? any helpful links ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Class JWTAuthorizationFilter.java

```
    package interv.Web.service;

import interv.Web.security.SecurityConstants;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

public class JWTAutorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", " Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Authorization");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");


        String jwtToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);

         if(httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")){
             httpServletResponse.setStatus(httpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        }
         else {
             if(jwtToken==null || !jwtToken.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)){

                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);

                 return ;
             }

             Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX,""))
                    .getBody();

            String username = claims.getSubject();
            ArrayList<Map<String,String>> roles = (ArrayList<Map<String,String>>)claims.get("roles");


            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            roles.forEach(r->{
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.get("authority")));
             });

            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken=
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,null,authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest,httpServletResponse);
         }

        }

    }
```

Error i get :

in ARC extention :

```
 {
"timestamp": 1526658417940,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException",
"message": "Unrecognized token 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTUyNzUyMjQxNywicm9sZXMiOlt7ImF1dGhvcml0eSI6IkFETUlOIn1dfQ.BtaWfqSy9xyDdZrEsJD6iJRVLyTpHEVGYL1NVR670Ts; line: 1, column: 21]",
"path": "/login"
}
```

In console :

```
    ERROR 4980 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTUyNzUyMjQxNywicm9sZXMiOlt7ImF1dGhvcml0eSI6IkFETUlOIn1dfQ.BtaWfqSy9xyDdZrEsJD6iJRVLyTpHEVGYL1NVR670Ts; line: 1, column: 21]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2839) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1903) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:749) ~[jackson-core-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3850) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2397) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at interv.Web.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:83) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at interv.Web.service.JWTAutorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAutorizationFilter.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manipulate the jwt manually with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind):

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    User springUser = (User)authResult.getPrincipal();
    String jwt = Jwts.builder()
    .setSubject(springUser.getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SecurityConstants.SECRET)
            .claim("roles",springUser.getAuthorities())
            .compact();
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode jsonJwt = objectMapper.readTree(jwt);
   ((ObjectNode)jsonNode).put("userId", getUserId(springUser));

   response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING,SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonJwt));       

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not using OAuth2 in my configuration and i don't have much infotmation about it can this be a problem ? as in this article they don't mention the imports etc

Comment: Ah i see , aren't there any other solution for those who use JWT only ?

Comment: There most certainly is. I can think of a manual way to it by manipulating a JsonObject and will rewrite my answer.

Comment: I appreciate this :) !

Comment: A question please : what about getUserId() ? from where you use this getter?

Comment: I added this to suggest some logic for getting the user id. This is entirely dependant on the specifics of your code. I imagine you will get the user id from the User object springUser. I will edit the code to show getUserId(springUser) to make that more clear.

Comment: not yet resolved , i'm still working on how to get the ID , can you see my question here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50397096/autowired-userrepo-findbyusername-caused-null-pointer-exception ?

Comment: In the case of your linked question either two things are happening. Either the UserRepo has not been wired or the User object (springUser) is null. Set a break point at the line which fails and use the debugger to see which one is null.

Comment: SpringUser returns the right information ,it's UserRepo that returns null like it's not autoweird .

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to tell why an object is not being autowired from the limited information you have given. But two things to try: Ensure that the Repository is in the a package that is being scanned, and change Component annotation on the Repository to @Repository.

Comment: i tried both solution but always same exception  , i wonder why i'm able to authenticate in angular5 while somthing like this happens

Comment: The only way I could diagnose this problem is if you create a github repo with enough code to demonstrate it.

Comment: thank you so much for help , finnaly i can try your solution , i've solved the previous problem